# What If 75% of Births Were Fatal?

Tags: society, population, female

How would society be different if it was human nature that 75% of all births were fatal, as in resulting in the death of the mother. The infants usually survive these births unharmed. There is no cure or medical treatment for this, no matter how technologically advanced society may become.

Additional questions: How would this affect population? How much lower would the population be today, probably?

*Note 1: It has always been this way biologically for humans.*

Comment: No humanity, soon. How long ago this supposedly started?

Comment: @Molot I'm asking this question as in what if it was like this from the very start, like it has always been human nature. But exploring the possibility of this randomly happening one day is interesting as well, if you or anyone wants to explore that.

Comment: I see that you changed your question quite drastically from 75% to 25%. If you continue this you may invalidate existing answers, which is something we don't like. We have a [Sandbox](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/635/sandbox-for-proposed-questions) on Meta where you can test questions before releasing them onto the main site and get feedback on style, on-topic/off-topic, grammar, flaws in your premise, ... Might be a good idea to give it a try next time. Currently it's okay with your edits, but please don't lower it any further. You can always ask follow-up questions

Comment: Do not  change  questions in a way that invalidates already posted answers.  See  this: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/43478/225745 - If you have to, then post a follow-up question with changed premise.

Comment: there would be less old women, not sure what the evolutionary advantage would be.

Comment: Your preposition is highly implausible. Such high childbirth mortality results in an incredibly high evolutionary advantage for those women who don't die during childbirth because they can have more offspring and nurture it after birth. Within a few tens of generations you'll either have no people left to give birth or they will have a far lower childbirth mortality.

Comment: This seems to be **too broad**.

Comment: The open ended unguided “what if” or “what does thaf do to society” is **too  broad**  for a question *here*.  You can discuss on [meta] or [chat] to get advice and and ideas in editing it, and note that the post can be reopened again after discussion.

Answer (score 12):

If it always been this way, then other things works really different, or there is no humanity.

Multiple children per birth are minority we can ignore for rough calculations. So there is 100% chance for first child to exist, 25% for second and ~6% for third. This gives us ~1.32 child per woman, on average. About 50% chance for a girl. So in each generation there is only ~66% of women that was in previous one. And that assuming they are guarded against all other reasons of death, which can't reasonably be true. Not many generations, and you don't have humans, because there is no one to give birth.

Ways to make humanity happen with this constrain are left for the author to decide. You need about one girl per women, and some boys, to have stable population. More than that to spread. When decided, we may answer next question, about society.

Comment: Assuming of course that the chance of each birth being fatal is independent of the last birth, which is unlikely.

Comment: @JoeBloggs Of course. But usually it's lower chance for successful birth after complicated  first pregnancy, so it is only worse than I answered.

Comment: If it's safely possible, you could abort most male fetuses or use artificial insemination to control the sex of the child.

Comment: @CodesInChaos Not in the beginning of human race, when we didn't really have medicine. Also, please use comments to point out mistakes, inconsistencies etc, or to request clarifications. Do *not* use them to make this site a discussion forum, it is not a forum and it's not what comments are for.

Comment: The "Multiple children per birth are minority" assumption is rather dubious as well, since is a strong evolutionary pressure to change that.

Comment: @CodesInChaos this falls into "other things works really different", the very first sentence of my answer. With only mother's death chance changed, ~3.5% of multiple birth pregnancies can be safely ignored.

Answer (score 8):

There are few animals for which reproducing brings to certain death. One of these animals is the octopus, which protects its eggs refraining from eating until (usually) starvation.

The difference between octopus and homo sapiens is that an octopuss lays thousands of eggs, so the net result is population increase. For a single birth this lethal outcome would turn into certain extinction over rather short time.

Moreover don't forget that human babies require high level of parental cares for years. Lowering the active parents to 1 will also lower the survival chances.

Comment: Alright I'm bringing it down to 25%, I'm trying to find the balance between not too much that it prevents the founding of civilizations or leads to extinction, but enough that it will change everyday life forever.

Comment: @Noble If your real goal was to find the ratio that makes it believable to create a society you should have said so in your question instead of assuming a percentage. Please leave the question as it is and try our Sandbox if you need a follow-up to find a better percentage.

Answer (score 6):

This depends.

Do you mean every single child born has a 75% chance of killing the mother or that 75% of births are fatal?

In the first case, see Molot's answer.

In the second case: [Fecund](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/fecund) women become *really, really* prized.

If 75% of births result in a death then we can expect the vast majority of deaths to be first time mothers, those that have never given birth before. These unfortunate souls can have only one child. The survivors, however, are those that are good at breeding.

At this point evolution takes over. Bloodlines known for multiple childbirths (especially multiple children per birth) will be highly desired, and since all the other bloodlines have died out (because of the imposed 75% death rate) the only ones surviving will be those where multiple births are the norm. Expect every pregnancy to result in at least twins, if not greater numbers of children (somewhat similar to [Saiga Antelope](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Saiga_antelope#Ecology_and_behaviour)). Large families with lots of half-siblings and stepmothers will be the norm.

I would expect such a society to value women for a very specific role, that of being pregnant and bearing multiple children. Which is not too dissimilar to the state of humanity less than a hundred years ago.

Comment: Somewhat confused about the downvote. Is there a specific reason I can address or is it just random dislike?

Comment: Don’t you just hate driveby downvotes?  Have to assume she doesn’t like the story you describe.  I don’t think this is deserving of downvoting.

Answer (score 4):

Because you are changing the rate of survival often, here is a simple computation.

This is a very rough approximation, but it gives an idea. A few assumption: With a high rate of death at birth, a large pressure will be put on women to have as much babies as they can. That's terrible, but let assume that they are force to give birth until they die. Raising babies will be the work of men. Of course, with such harsh conditions, women are protected and cared by men, so the only moment a woman can die is during birth. Assume no problem of sterility, and with high rate of death at birth, menopause is not an issue. We also ignore twins.

Then, consider a rate of survival at birth of $r$. That is, if $N$ women give birth, $rN$ of them will survive, and have to bear a baby again. On these $rN$, $r^2N$ will have a second baby; $r^3N$ lucky women will have a third baby and so on..

This means that the $N$ women will give birth to $N(1+r+r^2+\dots)=N\frac{1}{1-r}$ babies (geometric series). Half of them, that is $\frac{N}{2}\frac{1}{1-r}$, are girls. If you want a strict renewal of generations, you need $\frac{N}{2}\frac{1}{1-r}=N$, which means $r=\frac{1}{2}$, hence a rate of survival of $50\%$.

With same conditions, a smaller rate of survival will result in a population decreasing more or less slowly. A higher rate of survival means a growing population, or people can stop treating women like animals.

Answer (score 0):

You would quickly see a decline in population. Or you would need to make multiplicious pregnancies norm and high probability of females being born.

A women needs 10-15 years to be able to birth a child so let's assume we start with estimated population in 1500 which is 500 millions, they are all 15 years old. From that we assume that half are female and they go into pregnancy at the same time. After 9 months (let's say a year) you have 250 millions kids of which , let's say 75% are females.

So now we have 250 millions fertile men and 62,5 women. And one more year they give birth and 75% are females. So as you can see the amount of females would minish while the male population would steady grow.

You could go with `X-75%x`until you would end up with no women. I say 100 years tops.